# Determine if DataColumn is numeric

Tags: c#, numeric, datacolumn

Is there a better way than this to check if a DataColumn in a DataTable is numeric (coming from a SQL Server database)?

```
  Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();
  DbCommand cmd = db.GetStoredProcCommand("Get_Some_Data");
  DataSet ds = db.ExecuteDataSet(cmd);

  foreach (DataTable tbl in ds.Tables) {
    foreach (DataColumn col in tbl.Columns) {
      if (col.DataType == typeof(System.Single)
        || col.DataType == typeof(System.Double)
        || col.DataType == typeof(System.Decimal)
        || col.DataType == typeof(System.Byte)
        || col.DataType == typeof(System.Int16)
        || col.DataType == typeof(System.Int32)
        || col.DataType == typeof(System.Int64)) {
        // this column is numeric
      } else {
        // this column is not numeric
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

There is no good way to check if the type is numeric except comparing it to the actual types.
This is especially true if the *definition of numeric* is a bit different (in your case, according to code, - unsigned integers are not numerics).

Another thing is that [DataColumn.DataType according to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.datatype.aspx) only supports following types:

- Boolean
- **Byte**
- Char
- DateTime
- **Decimal**
- **Double**
- **Int16**
- **Int32**
- **Int64**
- **SByte**
- **Single**
- String
- TimeSpan
- **UInt16**
- **UInt32**
- **UInt64**
- Byte[]

The **bolded** types are numerics (as I define it) so you need to make sure you check them.

I personally would write an extension method for the DataColumn type (not for the TYPE!).
I hate the *if...then..else* thing so instead I use a *SETS*-based approach, like this:

```
public static bool IsNumeric(this DataColumn col) {
  if (col == null)
    return false;
  // Make this const
  var numericTypes = new [] { typeof(Byte), typeof(Decimal), typeof(Double),
        typeof(Int16), typeof(Int32), typeof(Int64), typeof(SByte),
        typeof(Single), typeof(UInt16), typeof(UInt32), typeof(UInt64)};
  return numericTypes.Contains(col.DataType);
}
```

And the usage would be:

```
if (col.IsNumeric()) ....
```

which is easy enough for me

Comment: I didn't include the unsigned integer types because they weren't listed in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092%28SQL.90%29.aspx but I do like your approach.

Comment: @JustinStolle, I would better include the unsigned types according to the MSDN page I provided. The page you reference is the SQL Server 2005 specific.

Comment: @Dmitriy, makes sense, thank you! FYI, you are missing a comma after "typeof(Double)" in your code sample.

Comment: Fixed that. That's the copy-paste's fault, not mine :)

Comment: Targeting .NET 2.0 I had to wrap the Array in an ArrayList to use the Contains method.

Comment: @Vincent, you don't need ArrayList. You can just do `Array.IndexOf(numericTypes, col.DataType) != -1`

Comment: This saved me some sanity! I also'd like to note, depending on your implementation and the source of the data, you may wish to add this before the second return statement: `if (col.DataType.IsArray) return numericTypes.Contains(col.DataType.GetElementType());` For example, if I have a DataTable filled with the results of an `ODBCDataReader` that came from querying an SQL Server 08 database, a column typed as `timestamp` on the server is translated into a `System.Byte[]` in the DataTable.

Answer (score 2):

Another method without using Arrays, just by one line of code:

```
return col != null && ",Byte,Decimal,Double,Int16,Int32,Int64,SByte,Single,UInt16,UInt32,UInt64,".Contains("," + col.DataType.Name + ",", StringComparison.Ordinal);
```

This can be used either as a normal helper method or as an extension method.

Comment: This is very inefficient! And incorrect for weird types called `mal` or `nt16`, for example.

Comment: @MicheldeRuiter Did you measure its efficiency? string.Contains() is very fast, probably faster than a loop through items of an array! about the data types, although we know those weird data types like nt16 not exist, but if you want to make the code bullet proof, you can add also a comma at beginning (as shown in edited post).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could make it shorter with:

```
System.Type theType = col.DataType AS System.Type
if(theType  == System.Single || theType  == System.Double...) {}
```