# Select Data from DataTable that are ISNUMERIC

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to select data from DataTable using ISNUMERIC function, unfortunately I get error below:

> System.Data.EvaluateException: "The expression contains the undefined
>   function call ISNUMERIC()."

this is my current code (sorry some parts are in German but to translate I don't think it makes sense)

```
 Public dtFakturas As New DataTable



  Artikelgruppe_Einfuegen(rows:=dtFakturas.Select("FAK_KundenNr = " & Adr_Nr &
                                                                " AND Liegenschaft = '" & Liegenschaft & "' " &
                                                                " AND Mandant = '" & Mandant & "' " &
                                                                " AND von = '" & VerrechnungsPeriode.Von & "'" &
                                                                " AND bis = '" & VerrechnungsPeriode.Bis & "'" &
                                                                " AND FAK_BoMatNr <> ''", "FAK_BoMatNr").Where(Function(r) IsNumeric(r("FAK_BoMatNr"))),
                                        Postable:=PosTable,
                                        Adr_Nr:=Adr_Nr,
                                        Mandant:=Mandant,
                                        Ueberschrift:="", MasterMandantConnectionString:=MastermandantConnectionString,
                                        Verrechnen_bis:=VerrechnungsPeriode.Bis)


 Private Function IsNumeric(ByVal o As Object) As Boolean
        Dim result_ignored As Decimal
        Return o IsNot Nothing AndAlso Not (TypeOf o Is DBNull) AndAlso Decimal.TryParse(Convert.ToString(o), result_ignored)
    End Function
```

my question is: how do i correct a select query to function properly and only give me values that are ISNUMERIC?

Comment: Most of the information in the question is not relevant, and what would be relevant is missing. If `Artikelgruppe_Einfuegen` calls [`DataTable.Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.select?view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_DataTable_Select_System_String_), which has nothing to do with SQL or querying a database, then your options are listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: @GSerg thanks for the reply, could you please give me an example that could correct my choice

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check datatable column contains numeric values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8836002/check-datatable-column-contains-numeric-values)

Comment: @GSerg ok I included this example you gave me, can you help me and tell me how to include in the "Dim filtered" other criteria that were applied in dtFakturas.Select.

Comment: IsNumeric is a reserved word of Visual Basic. 
Rename your function in IsThisNumeric or something else.

Comment: @G3nt_M3caj `IsNumeric` is not a reserved word in Visual Basic. It is a function in  `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Information`. It is not a problem to define your own function with the same name.

Comment: @Mara `dtFakturas.Select("FAK_KundenNr = ...").Where(Function(r) IsNumeric(r("FAK_BoMatNr")))`?

Comment: @GSerg aha, I'll try so, thanks with the suggestion

Comment: @Gserg, Thanks for your reply. I knew what is IsNumeric otherwise I doesn’t write a comment under this question. But, always is better practice using custom names in methods and variables.
Was this my context/advice. :)

Comment: @GSerg I corrected the code in question, now I'm getting this error, can you please look where I'm wrong ("System.InvalidCastException: "The object of type" WhereArrayIterator`1 [System.Data.DataRow] "cannot be converted to type" System.Data.DataRow [] "."")

Comment: @Mara Append `.ToArray()`.

Comment: Just throwing it out there since I can't see the full code; what if you change `Private Function IsNumeric` to `Public Function IsNumeric`?