# Why does IS check not work for datarow

Tags: c#

I have a datarow that has an integer in one of the columns. However the following code does not evaluate as true. I'm having a hard time understanding why. What am I missing?

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dataset.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    //this evaluates as false, even when I have a valid castable INT value in the column (as an object).
    if (dr[3] is int)
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt32(dr[3]) == 3)
        {
            //do something with row

        }
        else if (Convert.ToInt32(dr[3]) == 4)
        {
            //do someting else with row

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint and see what data type it is? That it can be converted to int doesn't mean it is an int.

Comment: That isn't a cast, its a convert.  Its probably a string.

Comment: Maybe this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725903/determine-if-datacolumn-is-numeric) will help you

Comment: In addition, do the conversion once and do your comparisons against the varaible.  Should prolly look in to the `switch` statement too.

Comment: If you run `dr[3].GetType().ToString()` what do you get?

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, you probably have a string which can be *converted* to an int, but not casted to an int.

Try this:

```
int val;

if (Int32.TryParse(dr[3].ToString(), out val)) {
```

Comment: While this is a correct answer, I'm curious why OP wants to check whether Tables[0].Columns[3] is an int for each row, given the table definition won't change during the execution. Is that really what he wants to know, or is there a better solution for the problem at hand?

Comment: Quite possibly the table contains disparate types of data and doesn't have a defined data type.

Comment: Like an int for one row, a datetime for the other and a decimal for the next, all stored in a varchar column? Then that is the problem that needs to be solved, not the parsing.

Comment: This works great aquinas, thank you. Of course, once this was in, switching on var was a great idea, thank you too Dan-o. I dont have any control over the database that generates this datatable and I want to insure that this piece of code wont grind to a hault if somehow a 'three' gets passed to me in this column.