# How to check if column can be converted to double? (DataTable.Column.DataType)

Tags: c#, if-statement, types

I need simple condition to replace this (incomplete) `if` condition.

```
// i dont want to write all possible data types
if (col.DataType == typeof(int) || col.DataType == typeof(int64) ... all types)
{
    // i want to do something on numeric columns
    // (convert all numbers to double datatype)
}
else
{
    // string and other non-numbers will remain unchanged
}
```

I was trying something like this:

```
col.DataType.IsNumeric()
```

but there is no such method in that class.

I cant use `TryParse()` method on data because there is too much data.

**Condition must be determined only by DataTable column datatype property.**

Is there any simple method to simplify my `if`?

Comment: Possible repeated question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/894263/how-to-identify-if-a-string-is-a-number

Comment: @Javiere I dont want to determine if specyfic data/variable is convertable to number.

Comment: Before your edition, the question was repeated.Now I still understand you need to know if a type isNumeric, question which has been solved before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749966/c-sharp-how-to-determine-whether-a-type-is-a-number/13179018#13179018

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the DataType as you did, or make a function to do this (see this [Determine if DataColumn is numeric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725903/determine-if-datacolumn-is-numeric)):

```
public static bool IsNumeric(this DataColumn col) {

  if (col == null)
    return false;

  // all numeric types
  var numericTypes = new [] { typeof(Byte), typeof(Decimal), typeof(Double),
        typeof(Int16), typeof(Int32), typeof(Int64), typeof(SByte),
        typeof(Single), typeof(UInt16), typeof(UInt32), typeof(UInt64)};

  return numericTypes.Contains(col.DataType);
}
```

And use

```
if (col.IsNumeric()) 
{
   // the column is numeric
}
```

Now, for the content of your column, you could try using `double.TryParse()` method, something like this:

```
double temp;
if (double.TryParse(col["Column"].ToString(), out temp))
{
  // the content can be converter and you can read it from temp variable.
}
```

Comment: So there is no dedicated method for this, and I need list of all possible types. Thanks.

Comment: @Kamil i think this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8836054/1993545) provides a more readable solution

Comment: Yes, you have to use `DataType` property. You also can check if the type is `double?` (nullable), and sometimes your column can has a null value.

Answer (score 1):

You can also check `DataColumn.DataType.Name` property. like :

```
string[] IntType ={"Byte","Decimal","Double","Int16","Int32","SByte",
                "Single","UInt16","UInt32","UInt64"};

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("num", typeof(int));
    dt.Columns.Add("str", typeof(string));
    Program p=new Program();
    string type = dt.Columns["num"].DataType.Name;
    if (p.IntType.Contains(type))
    {
        //True
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
if(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Information.IsNumeric
    (
     Activator.CreateInstance(col.DataType
    )
   )
```