# DataTable operations

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I have loaded an excel file using OleDB connection. The code loads the excel file to a DataGridView. Now I want to use the values of this datatable, lets say sum, multiply all rows or columns. Over the net I have found only the static approach of doing this:

```
object 1 = DATATABLE.Compute("sum(NameOfTable)", "").ToString();
```

But since I load different excel files, I need a more genuine way. I have tried several different ways - add the values to a List or an Array but it does not seem to work. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by "static approach"?

Comment: That it will work only if I know the exact name the columns.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to iterate over datacolumns

```
  List<string> l=new List<String>();
            foreach (DataColumn dc in table.Columns)
            {
              var Sum= table.AsEnumerable().Sum(x => x.Field<double>(dc));
              l.Add(Sum.ToString());
            }
```

you may need to check if datacolumn is null and contains numeric type or not otherwise casting will throw an exception. [Here is a solution to check if datacolumn is numeric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725903/determine-if-datacolumn-is-numeric)